# Confirmation Dialog Box for OnCreate Event

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365

I am trying to create a dialog box as a warning to the user when trying to create an entity record in a custom entity.

I wrote a JS which I tried to trigger onSave of form. However, this dialog box is popping up in the loop. This is happening both when I accept or cancel the event.

```
function OnFormSave(executionObj) {
    var eventArgs = executionObj.getEventArgs();
    var formContext = executionObj.getFormContext();
  //  eventArgs.preventDefault();

    if (eventArgs.getSaveMode() == 70)//AUTOSAVE
    {
        eventArgs.preventDefault();
        return;
    }

    var confirmStrings = { text: "Are you sure you want to continue to save the record?", title: "Warning" };
    var confirmOptions = { height: 250, width: 500 };
    Xrm.Navigation.openConfirmDialog(confirmStrings, confirmOptions).then(
    function (success) {
        if (success.confirmed)
        {
           // formContext.data.save();
        }
        else {
            eventArgs.preventDefault();
          
        }
    });
}
```

Can someone help me with this? Also, this event should happen only when the record is create. Any fix for that?

Comment: Any follow up questions?

Comment: @ArunVinoth I posted the solution I tried and worked for the above problem. If you could help me with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65908747/escape-timeout-limit-for-reports-in-dynamics-365-online questions, it will a great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to answer this in a little different way:

```
var count = 0;

function OnFormSave(executionObj, para) {
    var eventArgs = executionObj.getEventArgs();
    var formContext = executionObj.getFormContext();

    if (count == 0) {
        eventArgs.preventDefault();
    }

    if (formContext.ui.getFormType() == 1 && para != null && count < 1) {


        var confirmStrings = { text: "Are you sure you want to continue to save the record?", title: "Warning" };
        var confirmOptions = { height: 250, width: 500 };
        Xrm.Navigation.openConfirmDialog(confirmStrings, confirmOptions).then(
            function (success) {
                if (success.confirmed) {
                    count = count + 1;
                    formContext.data.save();
                }
                else {
                    eventArgs.preventDefault();

                }
            });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if the form type is in create mode and execute the Dialog prompt code then. This will work.

```
var formType = formContext.ui.getFormType();

if(formType == 1) { //create form

    // move your code here to execute only in create form mode
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would seperate the prevent auto save functionality and the open dialog functionality

```
function preventAutoSave(executionContext?: Xrm.SaveEventContext<any>) {
        if (executionContext == null) return;
        var eventArgs = executionContext.getEventArgs();
        if (eventArgs.getSaveMode() == 70) {
            eventArgs.preventDefault();
        }
    }
```

Keep in mind that the `successCallback` of the `openConfirmDialog` is being invoked when the dialog has been successfully opened and closed (either cancel pressed or ok button)

> A function to execute when the confirmation dialog is closed by clicking the confirm, cancel, or X in the top-right corner of the dialog.

If you want this dialog on the `onSave` of the form then consider on the `onLoad` of the form to add:

```
let form = executionContext.getFormContext();
// Assuming you want to prevent auto save all times
form.data.entity.addOnSave(preventAutoSave);
form.data.entity.addOnSave(openConfirmDialog);
```

---

```
function openConfirmDialog() {

    var confirmStrings = { text: "Are you sure you want to continue to save the record?", title: "Warning" };
    var confirmOptions = { height: 250, width: 500 };
    Xrm.Navigation.openConfirmDialog(confirmStrings, confirmOptions).then(
    function (success) {
        if (success.confirmed)
        {
           // formContext.data.save();
        }
        else {
            eventArgs.preventDefault();
          
        }
    });
}
```